# Data types supported in Storm and Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-storm, spark-streaming

I am new to Storm and Spark. I just would like to ask how these two frameworks store files? Can they use HDFS? Also, can they support xml format?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about spark but storm can write onto HDFS
https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-hdfs

apart from just HDFS it allows you to write onto hbase, redis and gives you a jdbc connector module as well. you can see the list here -
https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external

Answer (score 0):

As far as Spark is concerned, it can read and write on HDFS and it supports xml format just as Hadoop does.